# count(*) vs count(column-name) - which is more correct?

Tags: sql, count

Does it make a difference if you do `count(*)` vs `count(column-name)` as in these two examples?

I have a tendency to always write `count(*)` because it seems to fit better in my mind with the notion of it being an aggregate function, if that makes sense.

But I'm not sure if it's technically best as I tend to see example code written without the `*` more often than not.

**count(*):**

```
select customerid, count(*), sum(price) 
from items_ordered
group by customerid
having count(*) > 1;
```

**vs. count(column-name):**

```
SELECT customerid, count(customerid), sum(price)
FROM items_ordered
GROUP BY customerid
HAVING count(customerid) > 1;
```

Answer (score 209, accepted):

- `COUNT(*)` counts all rows
- `COUNT(column)` counts non-NULLs only
- [`COUNT(1)` is the same as `COUNT(*)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1221649/27535) because 1 is a non-null expression

Your use of `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(column)` should be based on the desired output *only*.

Comment: there is a performance difference (at least in MySQL) as well (see my answer).

Comment: To be exact, COUNT(column) counts rows in which values of column is not NULL, whereas COUNT(*) counts all rows of the table.

Answer (score 48):

*This applies to MySQL. I'm not sure about the others.*

The difference is:

- `COUNT(*)` will count the number of records.
- `COUNT(column_name)` will count the number of records where column_name is not null.

Therefore `COUNT(*)` is what you should use. If you're using MyISAM and there is no `WHERE` clause, then the optimiser doesn't even have to look at the table, since the number of rows is already cached.

Comment: So I understand that count(col) is slower than count(*) because MySQL has to examine the rows to see if NULL, but if the column is defined as NOT NULL, then does it still matter?

Answer (score 24):

When it's an identifier (and guaranteed to be non-`NULL`) then it probably doesn't matter.

However, there *is* a difference between `COUNT(*)` and `COUNT(column)` in general, in that `COUNT(column)` will return a count of the non-`NULL` values in the column. There is also the `COUNT(DISTINCT column)` variant which returns the number of unique, non-`NULL` values.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there is possible difference in performance. Depending on your query, and the indexing of the table in question, it can be quicker to get the count from the index instead of going to table for the data. Thus you probably should specify the field name, instead of using *.

Answer (score 6):

Generally it's the same, but in details AFAIK **"count(*)" is better** b/c "count(columnname)" forces DB to execute a little more code to lookup that column name (but not necessary though).

Comment: It depends on the database, Oracle/MSSQL/MySQL/DB2 do it differently.