# SQL select COUNT issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I have a table

```
num
----
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
55
NULL
NULL
NULL
99
```

when I wrote

```
select COUNT(*) 
from tbl
where num is null
```

the output was 7

but when I wrote

```
select COUNT(num) 
from tbl
where num is null
```

the output was 0

what's the difference between these two queries ??

Comment: A possible duplicate of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003457/count-vs-countcolumn-name-which-is-more-correct

Comment: possible duplicate of [In SQL, what's the difference between count(column) and count(*)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59294/in-sql-whats-the-difference-between-countcolumn-and-count)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Difference is in the field you select.

When counting `COUNT(*)` NULL values are taken into account (count all rows returned).

When counting `COUNT(num)` NULL values are NOT taken into account (count all non-null fields).

That is a standard behavior in SQL, whatever the DBMS used

[Source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count). look at COUNT(DISTINCT expr,[expr...])

Answer (score 0):

`count(*)` returns number of rows, `count(num)` returns number of rows where `num` is not `null`. Change your last query to `select count(*) from test where num is null` to get the result you expect.

Answer (score 0):

`Count(*)` counts the number of rows, `COUNT(num)` counts the number of **not-null** values in **column num.**

Comment: But there are two `NOT-NULL` values there in `num` column so when the output was 0 don't you think that it should be 2 ??

Comment: That would be the case if you hadn't added this where clause: where num is null :-)

Answer (score 0):

In second case first count values are eliminated and then where clause comes in picture. While in first case when you are using `*` row with null is not eliminated.

If you are counting on a coll which contains null and you want rows with null to be included in count than use

```
 Count(ISNULL(col,0))
```

Comment: ISNULL() is non-standard SQL and might or might not work depending on the RDBMS used by the OP.

Answer (score -1):

Considering the output given above, the result of the query count(num) should be 2.

Comment: Yes that's what bugged me too. But why the output was 0.

Comment: That would be true if the query didn't contain a where clause selecting only those rows with "where num is null"