# error code: 1054: unknown column

Tags: mysql

I am trying to execute the following statement:

```
DELETE a
FROM db.table1 a
    INNER JOIN (SELECT domainname
                FROM db.table1
                WHERE domainname LIKE '%.uci.edu'
                GROUP BY keyvalue
                HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
        ) b ON a.id = b.id
```

I got the error mentioned in my title. What I'm trying to achieve has been explained here: [How to make the result of one query be in the NOT IN clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11829050/how-to-make-the-result-of-one-query-be-in-the-not-in-clause)

Please, help me to do this task. Why b.id is unknown ?? I have no experience in such type of Join. I understand joining two different tables, but for this statement can anybody explain please ? Please, note that the `domainname` is unique value. The primary key is the `id` and it is auto_increment but I don't use it to differentiate between columns. I mainly use another value `domainname_no` which is unique.

**EDIT:** THE command above does not work.

what I need is the following :
I have a list of domain names. say: aa.yahoo.com, bb.yahoo.com, cc.yahoo.com, aa.msn.com. Each domain name has a key value. If the key is shared, I want to delete this record. So, I selected the distinct values grouped them by the key value. If the record in not in the distinct set, and have the same top level domain, then I don't need it.

Example: My table:
cert_id | domainname            |      domain_certificate | key 
1       | a.yahoo.com           | a.yahoo.com_1           |5555
2       | a.yahoo.com           | a.yahoo.com_2           |6666
3       | b.yahoo.com           | b.yahoo.com_1           |5555
4       | b.yahoo.com           | c.yahoo.com_2           |6666

each domain might have more than one certificate associated with key. If one or more certificate with different domain name have the same key, I want to delete it.

Now, I have two domain names which are `a.yahoo.com` and `b.yahoo.com`have the same key. I need to delete `b.yahoo.com` and any domain name that have the same pattern like '%.yahoo.com' and not equal to `a.yahoo.com` which is the distinct value.

Currently, what I'm doing is quering the distinct values:

```
select distinct domainname 
from db.table1
where domainname like '%.uci.edu'
group by keyvalue
order by domainname
```

Then delete any value that is not in the distinct list and have the same pattern `%.yahoo.com`

```
delete from db.table1 where domain not in ( I type the list of distinct domain 
names manually)
and domainanme like '%.yahoo.com';
```

i hope the problem is clear now.

But this command does not work. For details see: [How to make the result of one query be in the NOT IN clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11829050/how-to-make-the-result-of-one-query-be-in-the-not-in-clause)

Comment: What is the `GROUP BY keyvalue`  supposed to do? Can you show sample data of the `domainname` table?

Comment: The keyvalue is a number for example. 867676. If found duplicate for two distinct domainnames, I want to delete the duplicated record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you did not specify the `ID` for the `SubQuery`. Try this instead:

```
DELETE a
FROM db.table1 a
    INNER JOIN (SELECT id, domainname             -- added ID field
                FROM db.table1
                WHERE domainname LIKE '%.uci.edu'
                GROUP BY keyvalue
                HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
        ) b ON a.id = b.id                        -- ID was used here
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not joining two tables, your joining table1 with the result of a query, and you're not including the id column in that query. Try `SELECT id, domainname` at the beginning of the subquery.