# How to count field values in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, count

My table -

```
pid     id  subject section
1        1  7            0
2        1  12           0
3        1  13           1
4        1  13           2
5        1  13           3
6        1  14           3
7        1  14           4
8        2  15           1
9        2  16           1
```

Result to be obtained -

```
id subject total
1    7      1
1    12     1
1    13     3
1    14     2
```

My Query -

```
SELECT DISTINCT(SUBJECT), count(section)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY section
WHERE id = 1
```

But this is throwing an error, let me know what I am doing wrong

Error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id = 1' at line 4: SELECT DISTINCT(SUBJECT), count(section) FROM mytable GROUP BY section WHERE id = 1
```

Comment: If you get an error message, please post it together with your questions. Error messages have a purpose: help diagnose issues. Don't make us guess.

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003457/count-vs-countcolumn-name-which-is-more-correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax error is due to a misplaced `WHERE` clause. It needs to go *before* `GROUP BY`. Additionally:

- You are grouping by the column you want to sum.
- You are using DISTINCT unnecessarily.

Query should be on this line:

```
SELECT SUBJECT, count(section)
FROM mytable
WHERE id = 1
GROUP BY SUBJECT
```

Comment: Perfect..working like a charm...thx a lot..and thanks for the comments..i am on learning mode..so it will really going to help me alot :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to `group by` `subject` since this is the distinct value. In that group you want to count the appearances of `section`.

```
SELECT 1 as id, subject, count(section) as total
FROM mytable
WHERE id = 1
GROUP BY subject
```

And since the `id` column is not in the group, you can select that static value or you could replace it with an aggregate function like `min(id) as id` instead of `1 as id`

Comment: It throws an error --> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id = 1' at line 4: SELECT 1 as id, subject, count(section) as total FROM mytable GROUP BY subject WHERE id = 1

Comment: sorry, I did not notice the wrong order of `where` and `group by`. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You want to group by subject rather than section.  And you don't need distinct--it is redundant with GROUP BY.

```
SELECT id, subject, count(section)
   FROM mytable
   WHERE id = 1
   GROUP BY id, subject
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUBJECT, count(section)
FROM mytable
WHERE id = 1
GROUP BY SUBJECT
```