# TSQL, Remove rows based upon Row-Index

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My Table is like this.....

---

```
**AttName**     **Title**        **Count_Index**

Red                Boys              1
Red                Girls             2
Green              Boys              1
Blue               Boys              1
```

I only Want to return...

```
Red  Boys        1
Red  Girls       2
```

Thats because I have Red with two entries, I want to skip/remove all the ROW(s) if their Count is ONLY 1. In other words I am only interested in rows if their count goes above "1".

Comment: Is `Count` a field, or a calculated count using the aggregate function?

Comment: its drived column using row_number() Function

Comment: why are people giving it down-vote.

Comment: Because you said : I have this , I want that. You forgot the part where you try something and tell us what you tried.

Comment: I just did not feel like POSTING my entire stored procedure, I tried to simplify it with some dummy data only so everyone can understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table1
 WHERE AttName IN (SELECT AttName FROM table1 GROUP BY AttName HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9103e/3)**

Output

```sql
| ATTNAME | TITLE | COUNT_INDEX |
---------------------------------
|     Red |  Boys |           1 |
|     Red | Girls |           2 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is tested.  I like using windowing functions when looking for things like duplicates.  Particularly because the avoids doing a subselect in a where clause, and from the same table twice.  Instead all the needed columns are already pulled in the subselect.  Although windowing function can be expensive sometimes.

```
Select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (Partition by AttrName Order By AttrName) --probably better to order by whatever the primary key is for consistent results, esepcially if you plan to use this in a delete statement
From (
  SELECT AttName, title, COUNT(AttrName) over (partition by AttrName) as cnt
  FROM yourtable
) as counted
Where counted.cnt > 1
```

Comment: Why the `Count(*)` and not `Count(AttName)` since it's the only count that matters...

Comment: And what about the fact that he wants the columns `AttName`, `Title` and `Count_indes` in the results ?

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk The difference is whether you want nulls counted or not.  Updated query based on feedback, thanks. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003457/count-vs-countcolumn-name-which-is-more-correct