# SQL Server count(column) query

Tags: sql, sql-server

In sql server, count(column) will count null columns too? I had this question in my exam and I got confused but in the end I gave the answer that yes count(column) will count empty column too. I was just wondering if I was right or wrong. Anyone have any idea about this?

Comment: The [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx) answers this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [count(\*) vs count(column-name) - which is more correct?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003457/count-vs-countcolumn-name-which-is-more-correct)

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I tried google but not got a proper answer to my qusetion.

Comment: In case of `count(column_name)`, `null` values are not taken into account.

Comment: @Yosi No, that's wrong. But suppose you were right. Then there would be absolutely no point to the column name being specified, since the number of rows does not depend on the column name.

Comment: @user2758530 Also `empty` value is different from `NULL` value, `empty` values will be counted by `COUNT(column)` but `Null` values will be discarded.

Comment: @snyder That depends on what you mean by "empty value", it's not a standard term. It could legitimately mean "null value", where an "empty string" is not an "empty value".

Answer (score 7):

What stopped you from checking it by yourself?

```
CREATE TABLE Test (VALUE VARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ('sdfsdf'), ('sdfgsdfg'),( NULL),( NULL);

SELECT COUNT(VALUE) FROM Test
```

Result:

```
COUNT(VALUE)
2
```

So the answer is **NO**. `COUNT(ColumnName)` does not count rows with `NULL` values.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6769f/2)

Comment: Your answer is incomplete(incorrect). What about `COUNT(*)`?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Question is about `COUNT(column)`, and so is the answer.

Comment: Actually I dont have sql server installed in my laptop. Thats why couldnt check. Anyways Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @user2758530 You can always use tools like [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/).

Comment: Ok, but it can cause confusion.

Comment: *"Actually I dont have sql server installed in my laptop"* `> cinst SqlServer2012Express` [use chocolatey](http://chocolatey.org/packages/SqlServer2012Express)

Answer (score 2):

Here's what the [BOL (Books OnLine) article about COUNT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx) has to say:

> COUNT(*) returns the number of items in a group. This includes NULL values and duplicates.
>
> COUNT(ALL expression) evaluates expression for each row in a group and returns the number of nonnull values.
>
> COUNT(DISTINCT expression) evaluates expression for each row in a group and returns the number of unique, nonnull values.

Comment: I think it would be better to also include the bit of the documentation where it says `COUNT(expression)` means `COUNT(ALL expression)`. "ALL: Applies the aggregate function to all values. ALL is the default." I can see someone reading this and thinking "But what about COUNT(columnname)? That isn't in your list."