# How is COUNT(*) different to COUNT(id)?

Tags: mysql, indexing, count

`COUNT(id)`: query cost: 463

[image: count id]

`COUNT(*)`: query cost: 91.47

[image: count *]

Can someone help me to understand why `COUNT(id)` is more expensive than `COUNT(*)`?

Comment: `Count(*) counts all rows` , And `COUNT(column) counts non-NULLs only ` and have to access every row to see if the value is null or not See this post [count(*) vs count(column-name)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003457/count-vs-countcolumn-name-which-is-more-correct)

Comment: What is the cost if you have a "covering index":  `INDEX(song_id, id)`