# How to find how many times X appears

Tags: sql, sql-server

Learning SQL using SSMS and I have been given a database and a 32 questions. I am working my way through  the questions and got suck on a question of "How many people live in each city?" I know how to get how many times a singular entry is but not multiple.

Table:

```
create table client
(
custref     smallint primary key,
firstname   Varchar(20),
lastname    Varchar(20),    
city        Varchar(20),
balance     decimal(10,2),
creditlimit     integer,
repref      smallint,
foreign key (repref) references rep (repref)
);
GO
```

Insert's:

```
insert into client values(124, 'Sally', 'Adams', 'Dunedin', 418.75, 500, 3);
insert into client values(256, 'Ann', 'Samuals', 'Palmerston', 10.75, 800, 11);
insert into client values(311, 'Don', 'Charles', 'Christchurch', 200.10, 300, 6);
insert into client values(315, 'Tom', 'Daniels', 'Christchurch', 320.75, 300, 3);
insert into client values(405, 'Al', 'Williams', 'Christchurch', 201.75, 800, 11);
insert into client values(412, 'Sandra', 'Adams', 'Palmerston', 908.75, 1000, 6);
insert into client values(522, 'Mary', 'Nelson', 'Christchurch', 49.50, 800, 3);
insert into client values(567, 'Jo', 'Baker', 'Dunedin', 201.20, 300, 3);
insert into client values(587, 'Judy', 'Roberts', 'Dunedin', 57.75, 500, 6);
insert into client values(622, 'Dan', 'Martin', 'Dunedin', 575.50, 500, 6);
insert into client values(635, 'Peter', 'Paulls', 'Dunedin', 100.56, 500, 3);
insert into client values(640, 'Margaret', 'Jones', 'Dunedin', 114.56, 800, 3);
insert into client values(649, 'Robert', 'McKenzie', 'Palmerston', 200, 500, 11);
insert into client values(675, 'Greg', 'Johnson', 'Christchurch', 15, 300, 6);
insert into client values(680, 'Peter', 'Yu', 'Dunedin', 10, 500, 6);
```

Comment: Be good to see what you tried and exactly where you got stuck.

Comment: @DaleK ah my bad I forgot to add this. I have tried using what doing what Juergen did below but maybe due to me using SSMS it didn't work :L

Comment: What is the relationship between a "person" and a "client"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate both the First name and Last name of the peoples to find the total Count

```
SELECT City,COUNT(CONCAT(Firstname,' ',Lastname)) AS Total_People
FROM CLIENT
GROUP BY City
```

Comment: why do you need to `concat()` the name in order to find the `count()` ?

Comment: Performance should be slightly better than mentioning the Column name rather than the *  -@Squirrel

Comment: I am not aware of that there is performance difference for this in `SQL Server`. Care to share some reference on this ?

Comment: COUNT(*) counts all rows ; 
COUNT(column) counts non-NULLs only  -- @Squirrel

Reference
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003457/count-vs-countcolumn-name-which-is-more-correct

Comment: @Thiyagu  . . . You have that backwards.  `count(*)` should be faster than any expression that refers to columns.  In fact, in some cases, it could be much, much faster (if the rows are wide and an index is available for the count).

Comment: But, In this Case Count(*) Counts the Rows both "null" and "Not null" Client Names in the Count, So that i am Concatenating the columns in the Above Query. -- @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @Thiyagu . . . There are no examples of `NULL` values in the data and no reason to think they are there.  You could also filter them out using a `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 2):

Aggregate functions like  `count()` are applied to each group if you define a group:

```
select city, count(*)
from client
group by city
```

Comment: @koopa . . . Assuming that you want to count clients, this is the better approach.  I also note that it appeared 12 minutes earlier.