# group by with condition on count(*)

Tags: sql, oracle, hive

I am trying to find the count of obsv_dt which has less than million records

```
 select obsv_dt,count(*) as c from table
 group by obsv_dt 
 having c<1000000
 order by c
```

is giving unable to resolve column 'c'. I get that 'c' is alias and this error is expected
How can i get this working?

Comment: `having count(*) <1000000`. (The SELECT list column alias c hasn't been defined when HAVING is evaluated.) However, c can be used in the ORDER BY.

Answer (score 1):

```
 select obsv_dt,count(*) as c from table
 group by obsv_dt 
 having count(*) <1000000
 order by count(*)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the alias before it has been calculated; try:

```
select
  obsv_dt,
  count(obsv_dt) as c
from
  table
group by obsv_dt
having count(obsv_dt) < 1000000
order by count(obsv_dt)
```

There is a subtle difference in using count(*) vs count(col). But often it does not matter. [count(*) vs count(column-name) - which is more correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003457/count-vs-countcolumn-name-which-is-more-correct)

Answer (score 0):

> Below is the precedence of sql clauses:
>
> 1. FROM clause
> 2. ON clause
> 3. OUTER clause
> 4. WHERE clause
> 5. GROUP BY clause
> 6. HAVING clause
> 7. SELECT clause
> 8. DISTINCT clause
> 9. ORDER BY clause
> 10. TOP clause
>
> Since HAVING clause is evaluated prior to the SELECT clause it is
> unware of the aliases. Similarly for all clauses except for ORDER BY
> where we can include the alias for sorting the result set.